# Python fsolve highly dependent on initial values (more than matlab)

Tags: python, matlab

I am new to python, transiting from Matlab. I wrote the following code to solve a nonlinear equation system but somehow failed in python. It worked in matlab fsolve for many initial values unless I put an extremely large number. But it only works for python fsolve if the initial value is close enough to the solution. I don't always have good initial guess to the problem so I want it to work most of the time. Thank you very much! Solution is [0.003,0.0053] according to Matlab.

Python code

```
     param = {'r': 0.04, 
     'mu': 0.112,
     'delta': 0.02,
     'alpha': 0.35,
     'g': 0.0187 + 0.5*0.16*0.16,
     'sigma': 0.20,
     'xi0': 0.02,
     'xi1':1.05,
     'lambda0':0.02,
     'lambda1':1.05};

     param['sgsq'] = 0.5*param['sigma']**2;
     param['g0'] = param['g'] - (param['mu'] - param['r']) - param['sgsq'];

    #%% Polynomial
    import numpy as np
    import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
    import scipy.optimize as spyopt

    param['coef'] = (- (param['r']+param['delta']), (param['g0']+param['delta']
                -param['sgsq']), param['sgsq'])

    charfun = poly.Polynomial(param['coef'])
    param['psi'] = np.max(poly.polyroots(param['coef']))
    param['halpha'] = poly.polyval(param['alpha'],param['coef'])

    def lumpyfun(x0, param0):    
xstar,B = x0
AIPx = - np.power(xstar,param0['alpha']) / param0['halpha']
BigA = ((1.0-param0['alpha'])*(B**param0['alpha'])/(1.0-param0['psi'])/param0['halpha'] 
        + (param0['lambda1']-param0['lambda0'])/(1.0-param0['psi']))
vprimex = param0['alpha']*AIPx/xstar + param0['psi']*np.power((xstar/B),(param0['psi']-1.0)) * BigA/B
vprimeB = (param0['psi']-param0['alpha'])*np.power(B,param0['alpha']-1.0)/(1.0-param0['psi'])/param0['halpha'] + param0['psi']*(param0['lambda1']-param0['lambda0'])/(1.0-param0['psi'])/B   
diffy = (AIPx + np.power(xstar/B,param0['psi']) * BigA - xstar*vprimex - param0['lambda1'], vprimex - vprimeB)
return diffy`def lumpyfun(x0, param0):

    #%% Solve the problem
    #worked      
    x0 = np.multiply(np.sqrt(-param['halpha']),(1.0,2.0))/100.0
    #lumpyfun(x0,param)
    spyopt.fsolve(lumpyfun, x0, args=param)

    # not worked      
    x0 = np.multiply(np.sqrt(-param['halpha']),(1.0,2.0))/10.0
    spyopt.fsolve(lumpyfun, x0, args=param, maxfev = 5000000)
```

Matlab code:

```
    r = 0.04;
    mu = 0.112;
    delta = 0.02;
    alpha = 0.35;
    g = 0.0187 + 0.5*0.16*0.16 ; % 0.0187 + 0.5*sigma*sigma;

    sigma = 0.20; % 0.16 default;
    a2 = 0.5*sigma*sigma;
    g0 = g - (mu-r) - a2; % risk-neutral growth;

    lambda0 = 0.02;
    lambda1 = 1.05;

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %h = @(x) sgsq05*x^2 + (mu+delta-sgsq05)*x - (r+delta);
    coef = [a2, (g0+delta-a2), - (r+delta)];
    halpha = polyval(coef,alpha);
    phi = max(roots(coef))

    x0 = realsqrt(-halpha)*[1;2]/10;

    options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','off','MaxFunEvals',2000);
    sol = fsolve(@(x)   diffinvestmentoption(x,phi,alpha,lambda1,lambda0,halpha), x0, options);


    function [diffy,X] = diffinvestmentoption(xin,phi,alpha,lambda1,lambda0,halpha)

    xstar = xin(1);
    B = xin(2);

    AIPx = -xstar.^alpha / halpha;
    %AIPB = -B.^alpha / halpha;
    BigA = (1-alpha)*(B^alpha)/(1-phi)/halpha + (lambda1-lambda0)/(1-phi);
    vprimex = alpha*AIPx/xstar + phi*(xstar/B)^(phi-1) * BigA/B;
    vprimeB = (phi-alpha)*(B^(alpha-1))/(1-phi)/halpha + phi*(lambda1-lambda0)/(1-phi)/B;

    diffy = [AIPx + (xstar/B)^phi * BigA - xstar*vprimex - lambda1;
            vprimex - vprimeB];
```

Comment: For the one not working, the message was: "RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)"

Comment: Dear all. I am not asking this question for fun. This is a small piece of my big project which I need to eventually conduct simulated method of moments to estimate the parameters here (dict param). So the process is fully automatic and I don't want to feed python the appropriate initial values  in a small range manually. Any suggestions are appreciated. My original codes are written in Matlab + Fortran. But I am leaving the current institution so I may no longer have access to Matlab.

Comment: It's kind of hard (very very hard) to compare w/ matlab if there's no matlab code present...

Comment: Dear Hiandbaii, please see the codes here. I don't know how to get them aligned, sorry. The function in matlab `function [diffy,X] = diffinvestmentoption(xin,phi,alpha,lambda1,lambda0,halpha)

xstar = xin(1);
B = xin(2);

AIPx = -xstar.^alpha / halpha;
%AIPB = -B.^alpha / halpha;
BigA = (1-alpha)*(B^alpha)/(1-phi)/halpha + (lambda1-lambda0)/(1-phi);
vprimex = alpha*AIPx/xstar + phi*(xstar/B)^(phi-1) * BigA/B;
vprimeB = (phi-alpha)*(B^(alpha-1))/(1-phi)/halpha + phi*(lambda1-lambda0)/(1-phi)/B;

diffy = [AIPx + (xstar/B)^phi * BigA - xstar*vprimex - lambda1;
        vprimex - vprimeB];`